# Finding the cause/line of "Unexpected token ;" error in Express-JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, parse-platform

I am using Parse with Express-JS. I am trying to display an EJS page but I'm getting an `Unexpected token ;` at the server (when command line `parse develop MyApp` is running at Terminal). Here is the full stack trace of the error:

```
I2014-08-02T15:07:19.886Z]SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;
at Object.Function (<anonymous>)
at exports.compile (ejs.js:256:12)
at Object.exports.render (ejs.js:295:10)
at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (ejs.js:325:22)
at View.render (express_view.js:77:8)
at Function.app.render (express_application.js:516:10)
at res.render (express_response.js:763:7)
at userQuery.find.success (app.js:31:10)
at Parse.js:2:5906
at e (Parse.js:2:5101)
```

My `app.js` has:

```
app.get('/:username', function(req, res){

    Parse.initialize("...", "...");
    var userQuery = new Parse.Query("_User");
    userQuery.equalTo("username", req.params.username);
    userQuery.find({
      success: function(results) {
        var usr = results[0];
        res.render("user", {user : usr});
      },

      error: function(error) {
        alert(error);
        // error is an instance of Parse.Error.
        res.send(404, 'User not found!');
      }
    });

});
```

The problem is I have no idea where this error is occuring. I've commented out all the script tags in my HTML of the ejs file but I'm still getting the same error. When I try another ejs file, my app works, so there's a problem with that particular ejs file's contents. How can I find the line number of the error?

Comment: usually if i saw the same message, it means I didn't really parse the data to the page, it might be null or empty array , you can check it twice.

Comment: I've temporarily erased all the variables that I'm sending to the page, and I've commented out *ALL* the javascript in my page. I've searched for every single `;` character, and all of them are inside the completely commented out Javascript. But I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: error handling in node could be a hell of a lot better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message

```
at Object.Function (<anonymous>)   
at exports.compile (ejs.js:256:12) 
at Object.exports.render (ejs.js:295:10)  
at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (ejs.js:325:22)  
at View.render …
```

suggest that the [`Function` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) hit a syntax error when trying to compile a view. The mistake is not in your `app.js`, you should have a look at the View template that was used for rendering to user.

Comment: I've commented out the whole **already commented-out** javascript from my page and it started working. How on earth would a compiler throw an error about commented out code? (I'm using sublime text so if there was any error with commenting (e.g. double comment close token `*/`) it would also display incorrectly in sublime text. But it displays perfect both when I comment out or not comment out. I'll try to find the error in that Javascript now...

Comment: In what page, the compiled view? "compiling" usually means some kind of syntax munging to produce `eval()`able code, and the munging might not deal correctly with comments. Please post that code into your question if you need further clarification.

Comment: I've just found the error. It was inside the commented-out javascript, trying to parse `<%= user.getUsername() =>` line (removing it made it work again expect problems accessing that particular variable client side, obviously). It was a syntax error (closing with `=>` instead of `%>`) but Express/NodeJS/EJS engine (whichever is responsible) was giving the error even when all the code was compiled out, making me think that the error was caused by something else entirely.

Comment: Yeah, it probably just doesn't notice that your scripting tag ended (the match continues to the next `%>`), and tries to execute it as js verbatim.